# Database and SpringBoot in same Docker-Containter without password safe?

Tags: database, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I was wondering if it is safe to configure a DB without a password, when you deploy the SpringBootApp in the same container.

So that you dont have to expose the ports of the DB.

Roughly like this docker-compose.yml

```
version:'3'
service:
   myspringapp:
       ...
       dependson: 'mydb'
       ports:
         - 8080:8080
   mydb:
       ...
```

Now the DB should not be accessible for outstanding persons or am I missing something?

Comment: Great question, I too think it is safe!

Comment: Whenever you update your application code you’ll also have to restart the database.  You won’t be able to scale your application to multiple replicas.  You’ll have to manually monitor both processes to restart them if they fail.  This isn’t generally recommended Docker style, and it’s usually considered better to run things in separate containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze You are right, but what about the question? Do you think it is safe?